# d3js make tooltip stay when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a text and I want to show a tip over it when I put my mouse on it. This is achieved. Now I want the tip to stay once I clicked on this text, and disappear when I click on the text again. How can I do this? It seems that 'tip.show' does't work for this purpose...

```
nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
      .style("font-weight", function(d) { return d.father == undefined ? "":"bold";})
      .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.father == undefined ? "":"14px";})
      .on('mouseover', tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

The definition of 'tip':

```
  var tip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function(d) { return "index: " + d.index + "<br>other information..."; });

  svg.call(tip);
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign a flag to track if it's hidden or not. Then bind it to your click event rather than mouseover.

```
var clickFlag = false;

nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
      .style("font-weight", function(d) { return d.father == undefined ? "":"bold";})
      .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.father == undefined ? "":"14px";})
      .on('click', function(d){
          if(clickFlag){
             tip.hide(d);  
          }else{
             tip.show(d);  
          }
          return clickFlag = !clickFlag;
      })
```

Comment: Thank you ! The if condition works well but the tip just doesn't show... :(

Comment: yes I tried and that gives me a very strange error so I think it should be without ()

Comment: @jiayi I updated my answer use `tip.show(d)`/`tip.hide(d)`

Comment: hey but as there's the variable 'clickFlag', only one tip can be shown at a time. Is there any way to let several tips shown together ?

Comment: @jiayi Of course; flag variable is just for an example. You can define the flag inside the datum like `d.showFlag = false` etc. and check from there for each click object(text).

Comment: sorry how can i define the flag inside d?

Comment: @jiayi You can either define it when you are giving your data or after that you can iterate through all the nodes and add a flag. By before I mean to change your data structure like you are selecting `d.name` and stuff so give another key `flag`. By after: `d3.selectAll(".node").filter((node)=> {
           node.flag = false;
        })`

Comment: If you can add where you are giving your data to your nodeEnter I can update my answer.